# A group of order $2$ in a group of order $60$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If we assume that the $2$, $3$, and $5$ Sylow subgroups of a group $G$ of order $60$ are not normal, how can I show that a group of order $2$ in $G$ cannot be normal?

I was trying to use contradiction. Assuming that a group of order $2$ (call it $H$) is normal, we would also have subgroups of order $|P_3H|=6$, $|P_5H|=10$, and $|P_2H|=8$ in $G$. We know that the possible normalizers are $|N(P_3)|=6, 15$, $|N(P_2)|=12$, and $|N(P_5)|=10$. So I was trying to connect these two in some way, but that doesn't really get me anywhere...

Comment: We cannot have subgroups of order $\,8\,$ in a group of order $\,60\,$ ...

Comment: One could count elements. Remember a normal subgroup of order 2 is central.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks a lot, I didn't realize that. But I just thought about something else...I said that we would have a subgroup of order 8, thinking that at least one of the 2 sylow subgroups did not contain the normal subgroup of order two. But now I'm wondering if I was actually correct with that assumption...

Comment: $G/H$ is a group of order $30$, which has a normal Sylow 5-subgroup, so its preimage is normal...

Comment: No @Artus, it wasn't: any $p$-subgroup is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup, so that a normal subgroup $\,H\,$ of order 2 is contained in a Sylow $2$-subgroup $\,P\,$, and since any other Sylow $2$-subgroup is obtained by conjugating $\,P\,$ and $\,H\,$ is invariant under conjugation, $\,H\,$ is contained in every Sylow $2$-subgroup.

Comment: @JackSchmidt I'm not sure what you mean by counting elements. We know that we have 6 5 Sylow subgroups, and either 4 or 10 3 Sylow subgroups. So we either have (6)(4)+(4)(2)=32 or (6)(4)+(10)(2)=44 elements that do not have order 2 (or 4). So I'm not sure if that's what you meant...or maybe I misunderstood you.

Comment: My suggestion is to count the elements of order 1, 3, 5, 6, and 10. There are at least 1 + 8 + 24 + 8 + 24 = 65 of them.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Oh, so you're saying that...since we are assuming that a normal subgroup of order 2 exists (call it H), then $P_3H$ and $P_5H$ must also exist (since H is normal). And since the element of order 2 in H commutes with every element in G and since $P_3$ and $P_5$ are abelian themselves, then $P_3H$ and $P_5H$ must also be abelian. So we have elements of orders 6 and 10, right? I just want to make sure if I understood it correctly.

Comment: @Artus: yes, exactly